# IE 8,9 z-index bug

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, z-index

I have some troubles with a website I'm working on.

The dropdown in the menu works fine in all browser except < IE10. I'm trying to get it to work on IE8+.

The thing is, the dropshadow and border of the dropdown is shown, but all content inside it is hidden when outside the header.

I've tried the classic bug-fix, which is to set the main-wrapper to position relative, and give the header-wrapper a higher z-index, but nothing happens.

The website: http://playground.pixby.se/startup/index.html

Comment: Code? Please? We don't know which div you're talking about. You haven't given us any id or class names..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've played around your CSS and when you turn off the filter property used for the gradient on the header element, the menu displays on IE8.

Comment: Yes, it was a crazy bug.. I first went and tried adding position and z-index to all parent elements and when it didn't work, I knew there must have been something in the CSS that was making an issue, since everything was coded properly in HTML. Anyways, glad I could help. Cheers!